# Converting a 3D matrix into vertically cascaded 1D arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization, reshape

Is there any shortcut to the for loop in the following piece of code?

```
import numpy as np

ff = np.zeros((3,3,4))
gg = np.zeros((36,1))

ff[:,:,0] = 1
ff[:,:,1] = 2
ff[:,:,2] = 3
ff[:,:,3] = 4


for ii in xrange(4):
    gg[ii*9:(ii+1)*9,0] = ff[:,:,ii].reshape((9,))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) or [`swapaxes`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) with some `reshaping` -

```
ff.transpose([2,1,0]).ravel()[:,None]

ff.swapaxes(0,2).ravel()[:,None]
```

You can replace the `ravel` with `reshape` -

```
ff.transpose([2,1,0]).reshape(-1,1)

ff.swapaxes(0,2).reshape(-1,1)
```

Comment: smart answer. Thanks!